# Spring no setter found for property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to make a configuration `data class` in Kotlin with Spring Boot. I have the following class:

```kt
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.braintree")
data class BraintreeConfigProperties(
    val merchantId: String = "",
    val publicKey: String = "",
    val privateKey: String = "",
    val environment: Environment = Environment.SANDBOX
)
```

And the following properties:

```properties
spring.braintree.merchantId=${BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID}
spring.braintree.publicKey=${BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY}
spring.braintree.privateKey=${BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

When I run the application I get the following exception:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.braintree' to com.x.ps.config.BraintreeConfigProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$311e0531:

    Property: spring.braintree.merchant-id
    Value: ${BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID}
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 5:29
    Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No setter found for property: merchant-id

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

However, I also have a class which is exactly the same as the `BraintreeConfigProperties` class. This class (`DatabaseConfigProperties`) does work. They are completely identical.

What I've tried:

1. Checked if the property names actually match with the configuration names.
2. Tried all three configuration properties separately.
3. Attached a non environment variable with value 1234 to the merchantId property which results in the following exception:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.braintree' to com.x.ps.config.BraintreeConfigProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62509e61:

    Property: spring.braintree.merchant-id
    Value: 1234
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 5:29
    Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No setter found for property: merchant-id

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proplem here ist that `val` is final and `var` can be changed. So you should change your properties to `var`.

More Info here: https://medium.com/mindorks/kotlin-series-val-vs-var-difference-android-kotlin-ecad780daeb7

Comment: This actually was the problem. I went back to my other class and indeed it had var declarations, not val. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot accept the answer so fast, so I will do so in ten minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin only generates a getter, when declaring a field as `val`. Spring however uses a setter to inject values from properties into the object.

With newer versions of Spring Boot you can make use of `data class`es with `val` fields, by injecting values through the constructor instead of using setters.

You can do so by using `@ConstructorBinding`, see the following example from the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.kotlin.configuration-properties):

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("example.kotlin")
data class KotlinExampleProperties(
        val name: String,
        val description: String,
        val myService: MyService) {

    data class MyService(
            val apiToken: String,
            val uri: URI
    )
}
```

While using lateinit var or a var that's initialized to null works too. Most likely you don't want to change those fields after initialization, thus `val` seems to fit better most of the time instead of declaring a `var` and generating a setter under the hood.